# onDraw is only called once even though invalidate was called multiple times

Tags: android, canvas, ondraw, invalidation

I know there are many similar questions, but none of the answers seem to apply, so maybe someone can spot what I'm doing different.

In my activity, I launch a popup window that includes a canvas and it's supposed to draw a chart of 3 bars. It works if I do 3 lines in the `onDraw` like this:

```html
        c.drawRect(160, 60, 800, 110, myPaint);
        c.drawRect(160, 160, 250, 210, myPaint);
        c.drawRect(160, 260, 400, 310, myPaint);
```

but I want to paramterize it and call it multiple times from a for loop in my activity. The problem is that only the last bar shows up and when I run through debugger or check via logcat, I see the 'setBar' (which has the `invalidate()` call) is executed 3 times, but `onDraw` only one time in the end.'

I added the `setWillNotDraw` to false, which was the main solution from the other posts. Here is my snippet from the activity where I call the popup:

```html
                statsDrawCanvas = (StatsDrawCanvas) popupView.findViewById(R.id.statsCanvasDraw);

                for (int day = 0; day <3; day ++) {

                    BarTop = BarTop + 100;
                    BarBottom = BarBottom + 100;

                    statsDrawCanvas.setBar(BarLeft, BarTop, BarRight, BarBottom);
                }
```

Here is my canvas class snippet:

```html
    public StatsDrawCanvas(Context context) {

        super(context);

        brush.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        brush.setStrokeWidth(20);

        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    public StatsDrawCanvas(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        super(context,attrs);

        brush.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        brush.setStrokeWidth(20);

        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {

        Log.i("LOG: (DRAW) ", "--- onDraw");

        CanvasWidth = c.getWidth();
        CanvasHeight = c.getHeight();

        Paint myPaint = new Paint();
        myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        myPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTeal1));
        myPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);

//        c.drawRect(160, 60, 800, 110, myPaint);
//        c.drawRect(160, 160, 250, 210, myPaint);
//        c.drawRect(160, 260, 400, 310, myPaint);

        c.drawRect(barCoordLeft, barCoordTop, barCoordRight, barCoordBottom, myPaint);

    }

//**********************************************************************************************
    //***   Method: Set Bar Data
    //**********************************************************************************************
    public void setBar(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {

        barCoordLeft = left;
        barCoordTop = top;
        barCoordRight = right;
        barCoordBottom = bottom;

        Log.i("LOG: (DRAW) ", "--- setBar");

        invalidate();
    }
```

Am I misunderstanding how `onDraw` works? I want to draw a bar x-times with slight offsets and add some more text to it (later). This should work i.e. incrementally calling the `onDraw`, it's not cleared or reset somehow, right ?

Comment: "Am I misunderstanding how `onDraw` works?" - It sounds like it. Each time `onDraw()` is called, you're basically handed a fresh, blank `Canvas`. You need to draw the complete `View` each time. Since you currently have only the one `drawRect()` call there, you're only ever going to see one bar - the last one drawn. As for your log prints, I would have you guess that you're just somehow missing some of them.

Comment: oh, I thought it was the other way round i.e. one would have to go through the trouble of erasing all previously drawn objects. Well, that explains that I only see the last object, but still not sure why I don't see it in logcat or when I single-step through the debugger.   So how do I implement multiple bars if I can't call it incrementally? Should I create an array and pass on the array instead and implement a ``for`` loop inside onDraw? I see some people suggesting to take snapshots which sounds like total overkill, how do people design entire games based on ``onDraw`` ???

Comment: Yeah, an array, or a `List`, would work. The "snapshot" thing would work, too, but I agree that it would probably be overkill for something simple like you're doing here. As for how entire games are done like that, well, there's just a bunch of drawing going on in `onDraw()`. It's not a suitable technique for graphics-heavy games, but it's adequate for certain types of games that only need relatively primitive, flat graphics.